# Limit size of list in GSP

Tags: grails, collections, gsp

I'm displaying some values in an array. I would like to limit the list to an arbitrary value, and later by date.

In my model an account has many balances. And there are many balances, like on one year, and displayed everyday.

```
<g:each var="account" in="${account.list(sort:name)}">
    <tr>
        <td>${account.name}</td>
        <g:each var="balance" in="${account.balances.sort{it.date}.reverse()}">
            <td>${balance.amount}</td>
        </g:each>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Comment: you should move this logic from the GSP into a controller/service

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I thought it was easier to let this in the GSp if possible

Comment: Can you show the account and balance domain classes?

Comment: It's OK, I just added .take(10) at the end after reverse

Comment: such a setup does really scare me. Are you sure, you never get lazy-init-exception here? as you need to traverse at least through 3 different tables

Answer (score -1):

Just modified as

```
<g:each var="balance" in="${account.balances.sort{it.date}.reverse().take(10)}">
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing that sort of thing in a GSP.  The controller which is populating the model should put the results of all of this sorting and count limiting in the model and the GSP should just be rendering what is in the model.  Having this code in a GSP is potentially problematic for several reasons.

Comment: I did this but for other reasons. In fact I'm just working on a poc with Grails ;)